# Read data from excel file for analysis

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have the following two codes that I wrote and the excel file. I just don't understand how to combine them, so that I can read from the excel file and using those numbers make a cluster.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

fileWorkspace = 'C://Users/bob/Desktop/'

pull=[]
wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fileWorkspace + 'try.xlsx')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

for a in range(0,sh1.nrows):
    for b in range(0,sh1.ncols):
        pull.append(sh1.cell(a,b).value)
    print('Finished in row' + str(a))


x = [11,19,23,33,44,91,92,90,60,63]

y = [92,85,22,25,86,78,63,51,66,15]


X = [list(item) for item in zip(x,y)]

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["g.","r.","y.","c.","m.","k."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths=5, zorder=10)
plt.show()
```

The excel file image:
[image: Excel image]

It is complicated because I have to read that single row of data and then make clusters. Also I have to skip rows and columns to read them.

Comment: In your code it seems like you're not using the data loaded in from the excel file is that right? What exactly do you want to do with this data?

Comment: Yea. The data I have for that clustering code is just sample. The one in the excel file is the right one. The code definitely needs modification but I am stuck on how to combine those two codes. I pretty much want to read that excel file data and make clusters.

Comment: Alright, no problem so what do the numbers in the file represent? You'll need a predictor and predictand. In your example you have several x,y pairs. In the excel data it seems like there is only one column of data.

Comment: I just realized that K-means clustering requires x and y. I only have x. I guess I will have to use a different type of clustering. Possibly a network. But, still need to know how to read the excel data by skipping rows and columns and store them in an array. If you can help me with that for now, then that would be great.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well good luck with it! For reading the data in you might be interested in using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: `import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('try1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
print (data)`

Comment: This only works if the data starts at row 1 and column 1. I don't know how to read my data.

Comment: Ok no problem I think I can answer that. What I would suggest then is editing the question body/title/tags to include only the information related to reading the data as you've described it, then asking the clustering/network question separately.

Comment: I am sorry I had wrong image uploaded. Now it should be fine. We can continue with the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can use the [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in data from first sheet
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=0, parse_cols='B:D', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
```

That way you can deal with the blank column as well as the header and data labels at the same time. From there you can access the data via `df.values` in the form of a numpy array, or get a list of lists (y, x) pairs by doing:

```
pairs = df.values.tolist()
```

You can also use xlrd by iterating through the rows and/or columns using the appropriate ranges. For example, if you wanted to read in just the data in your example file into a list of lists you could do something like:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

pairs = []
# Iterate through rows starting at the 3rd row)
for i in range(2, 15):
    # Iterate through columns starting at the 3rd column
    pairs.append([sheet.cell(i, j).value for j in range(2, 4)])
```

There's probably a better way to do this in xlrd, but I rarely ever use it.

Comment: Thanks! I got that part. I will try to attempt doing the cluster code. If I don't get it, I will edit the post with it.

Comment: That was easy I just had to do `X = pairs`

Comment: And if you need (x, y) pairs instead of (y, x) you can do `X = [p[::-1] for p in pairs]`

Comment: What if I want to skip a column or a row? Like I want to read column 1 and column 3, and skip the data in column 2.

Comment: Figured out the skip column and used your switching x,y idea. Amazing! Thanks again.